# How to make Isotope and Wordpress work together?

Tags: theme-development, javascript, masonry

I am trying to make my Wordpress theme using Isotope plugin. 
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

So far, I have such a result after doing that was suggested:
[image]

I believe that Isotope Masonry should not look like this. I am really puzzled as to what I am doing wrong. Below is my code:

functions.php

```
 function profolio_scripts () {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'profolio-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_script("isotope", get_template_directory_uri () . "/js/isotope.pkgd.min.js",array("jquery"));
    wp_enqueue_script("imagesLoaded",get_template_directory_uri () . "/js/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js",array("jquery","isotope"));
    wp_enqueue_script("custom", get_template_directory_uri () . "/js/custom.js", array("jquery","imagesLoaded","isotope"));   
};
add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "profolio_scripts");
```

Javascript:

```
 jQuery(function($){
  var container=$("#isotope-container").imagesLoaded(function(){
      container.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        masonry:{
            columnWidth:160
        }
      })
   });
 });
```

CSS:

```
 .item {
    width:160px;
    margin: 1px;
 }
 #isotope-container {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:100%;
 }
```

And PhP code that works in the loop.

```
<?php
  get_header();
?>
<div id="isotope-container" >
    <?php
     if(have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        get_template_part("content");
      endwhile;
     endif;
    ?>
</div> <!--isotope-container-->
```

"content" template:

```
<div class="item">
  <?php
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
     $perm = get_permalink();
     $width = randomImageSize (200, 400);
     $height = randomImageSize (200, 400);
     $image = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array($width,$height));
   }
  ?>
    <a href="<?php echo ($perm);?>"><?php echo ($image);?></a>
    <div class="imageDesc">This beautiful image </div>
</div>
```

My guess is that the problem has to do with imagesLoaded method. The Isotope sort of works as the screenshot suggests, however, it does not work properly  - there is a lot of free space between images.

Please help resolve the issue

Comment: On what does this run? On posts? If so: Please show us (in an [edit]) your markup. I guess you are simply missing [the needed classes](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html)

Comment: It runs on post thumbnails - please see the edit

Comment: Yes, it seems like you are missing those classes. Please open up your browsers dev tools (Either `F12` _or_ `Ctrl + Shift + I`) and add in those classes manually to see if this is the problem. If it is, we can go on providing you an answer on **how to add classes to thumbnails**. Does this work for your? Please report back here and [edit] your question with your result and maybe a rephrased question and a new title for it.

Comment: What classes do you mean? In my Firefox debugging tool all classes .item, #isotope-container are in place

Comment: Ok, so may be Isotope masonry works if there are .item w1 and .item w2 with different width, for example? I cannot figure out this

Comment: May be images should be of the same size or may be imagesLoaded should be placed outside $(function($). I tried all this, but without success. Please, suggest any other troubleshooting

Comment: Thanks I'll try to figure out what you said :-) Basically, I did it just for test. What if I just populate .item with images with different sizes? Should I also leave .item class without preset width?

Comment: *Note:* This represents a problem also concerning the Masonry library of WordPress core. So please don't close this as not WordPress specific.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the WordPress Development model is available at the [help].

Comment: what do you mean with: "content" template: ? I'm trying my self to create a gallery like this

Answer (score 1):

The [*Isotope* documentation about *ImagesLoaded*](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/appendix.html) suggest two methods for this. I generally use the second one, which means: *initializing Isotope and trigger `layout` after the images have been loaded*. In my experience this works better, not that I have facts to proof it. Aside from that, I have it running this way successfully on a bunch of sites.

The javascript file looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var $container = $('#your-id');

    $container.isotope({
        layoutMode: 'masonry',
        itemSelector : '.your-class',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: 200,
        }
    });

    $container.imagesLoaded( function() {
        $container.isotope('layout');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but I don't have a masonry after doing this - see the updated image in my question

Comment: Too bad, can't tell why it isn't working on your setup. Like I said, this is generally the way I have it working just fine. @user3695711

Comment: Thanks. What about image sizes - now I upload thumbnails as they are without randomizing their size. And also I deleted width style for .item. However, still without success. Please, see the updated image again.

Comment: Like I said before, can't really tell with the information available. What I can tell you is, in my experience managing widths with classes works better then having totally random or percentage widths - depends on the layout though. Aside from that, you should read the documentation and/or some tutorials that are out there (again, maybe), because generally this is absolutely achievable. Good luck! @user3695711